# d3.js path d attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attributes

I am a new d3 user. I want to create an animation for a path created by `d3.arc()`.

My problem is, when the `mouseover` event on `g` element is triggered, the path is assigned a JavaScript function instead of an SVG `M` path. 
[image: path attribute d get d3.arc()]

I think the problem is with my use of `arcTween()` function when we return `arcs()` in the result.

```
            var outerData = [
  [{outerRadius: 90, innerRadius: 74, cornerRadius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: -5.34071}],
  [{outerRadius: 90, innerRadius: 74, cornerRadius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: -1.5708}],
  [{outerRadius: 90, innerRadius: 74, cornerRadius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: -3.76991}],
  [{outerRadius: 90, innerRadius: 74, cornerRadius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * Math.PI}],
];

function arcs(innerRadius, outerRadius, cornerRadius, startAngle, endAngle) {
  return d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
      .startAngle(startAngle)
      .endAngle(endAngle);
}

var svg = d3.selectAll('svg');

var path = svg.select('g')
    .data(outerData)
    .each(function (d) {
      d3.select(this)
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', arcs(
              d[0].innerRadius,
              d[0].outerRadius,
              d[0].cornerRadius,
              d[0].startAngle,
              d[0].endAngle))
          .attr("transform", "translate(90, 90)")
    })

svg.select('g').on('mouseover', function (d) {

d3.select(this).select('path')
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
.attrTween("d", arcTween(-4))
})

function arcTween(newAngle) {
  return function (d) {

    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d[0].endAngle, newAngle);

    return function (t) {

      d[0].endAngle = interpolate(t);

      return arcs(
          d[0].innerRadius,
          d[0].outerRadius,
          d[0].cornerRadius,
          d[0].startAngle,
          d[0].endAngle);
    };
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle with this code?

Comment: From the [attrTween](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween) documentation: "The interpolator must return a string." You must invoke the arc generator in `arcTween()` instead of returning it.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.
In the function 'arcs'. Instead of this variant i tried:
var arc = d3.arc(), and then return arc()